# MySQL JOIN two tables (Union)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two MySQL tables

first one is booking

```
+------------+--------------+---------+
| id         | contact_no   | date    | 
+------------+--------------+---------+
| p1         | 7898787946   | 15-06-05|
| p1         | 7897891562   | 15-06-05|
| p1         | 1546879585   | 15-06-07|
| p2         | 1789546528   | 15-06-07|
| p3         | 7894668265   | 15-06-07| 
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

second one is setup

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
| id         | date         | time | max |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
| p1         | 15-06-06     | 8.00 | 20  |
| p1         | 15-06-07     | 8.00 | 20  |
| p2         | 15-06-07     | 9.00 | 10  |
| p3         | 15-06-08     | 8.00 | 20  | 
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
```

I need to join two tables for particular id(let's say p1) and I wanted to exactly generate this table. count is the number of rows for particular date and id. (e.g count for 15-06-05 of p1 is 2)

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
| count      | date         | time | max |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
| 2          | 15-06-05     | null | null|
| 0          | 15-06-06     | 8.00 | 20  |
| 1          | 15-06-07     | 8.00 | 20  |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+
```

What will be the MySQL query can be used to generate this third table

I tried this SELECT COUNT(booking.date) as 'count', setup.time, booking.date, setup.max FROM booking LEFT JOIN setup on booking.date =setup.date and booking.id=setup.id and booking.id='p1' GROUP BY booking.date ORDER BY booking.date ASC"

Comment: I tried this
SELECT COUNT(booking.date) as 'count', setup.time, booking.date, setup.max FROM booking  LEFT JOIN setup  on booking.date =setup.date and booking.id=setup.id and booking.id='p1' GROUP BY booking.date ORDER BY booking.date ASC"

Comment: What was the output of your query ?

Comment: @PubuduNawarathna Please edit information into your question instead of commenting. Also, it will be easier to help you if you set up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any in the question that involves a Cartesian Product.

Comment: Also, why do you want the NULL is time and max when you have a count of 2, but populated when you have a count of 0?

Comment: @KarlKieninger that two different tables just need to check which rows consisted of count and which are not. and I thought Cartesian product might be helpful. sorry

Comment: why `15-06-06` has 0 count ? shouldn't be 1 from the given data ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty becuase in the booking table there is no any rows for 15-06-06. there for count should be 0

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but I can not check at the moment. It is a pain without `full join`s in `MySql`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(id1, id2), COALESCE(date1, date2), COUNT(*), MAX(time), MAX(max)
FROM
    (SELECT b.id as id1, s.id as id2, b.date as date1, s.date as date2, s.time, s.max FROM booking b
     LEFT JOIN setup s on b.id = s.id and b.date = s.date
     WHERE b.id = 'p1'
     UNION
     SELECT b.id as id1, s.id as id2, b.date as date1, s.date as date2, s.time, s.max FROM booking b
     RIGHT JOIN setup s on b.id = s.id and b.date = s.date
     WHERE s.id = 'p1') t
GROUP BY COALESCE(id1, id2), COALESCE(date1, date2)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer how can I filter data for one specific ID number. thank you